# Gedit or an other non-commandline editor with the ability to spell-check two languages at the same time

Tags: sed, editors, cat, gedit, spell-checking

I'm searching for an editor with the ability to spell-check two languages at the same time (German and English). Gedit can't do it out of the box.

But I want to use Gedit. It should be possible by merging the English and German dictionaries and select the created file under Tools->Set Language...

**edit**

I got it almost (some warnings in step 6 and e.g. `zzgl.` (words with a dot at the end) are not spell-checked) :) Thanks to your post Kevin Atkinson :)

(I may add that for English I used `aspell6-en-7.1-0.tar.bz2` (is already new version/updated) but for German I used `http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/dict-de_DE_frami` because it's more updated.
Extract this .oxt using `unzip`. In `de_DE_frami` are the two needed affix and dictionary files called `de_DE_frami.aff` and `de_DE_frami.dic`.
Rename the `de_DE_frami.aff` to `qed_affix.dat` and the `de_DE_frami.dic` to `de.txt`.

Note: For German there is also an extension: `http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/de/project/DFEW` which I'm going to merge later too)

In step 6 I had to use 
    `$ cat de_en | aspell --encoding=utf-8 create master -l ./qed ./qed.rws`
because all üäöß.. were skipped and were not in the created dictionary, but now they are there:
    `$ aspell -d ./qed.rws -a`
    (Testing: typing e.g. "Käse" or "zweiunddreißig" prints an *, so it finds these words now)

```
Filesizes: $ du -b qed*
18725   qed_affix.dat
103 qed.dat
12  qed.multi
6763456 qed.rws
```

```
Lines: $ wc -l qed* de_en
       6 qed.dat
       1 qed.multi
   54403 qed.rws
     717 qed_affix.dat
  334974 de_en
```

[Download](http://www.file-upload.net/download-4672074/de_en_merged.tar.bz2.html) of this package in case someone needs it.

The most warnings I can see now at step 6 look like this - last 5 lines:

```
$ cat de_en | aspell --encoding=utf-8 create master -l ./qed ./qed.rws
...(many warnings appear)
Warning: Removing invalid affix 'o' from word zytostatika.
Warning: Removing invalid affix 'z' from word zytostatika.
Warning: Removing invalid affix 'o' from word zytostatikum.
Warning: Removing invalid affix 'z' from word zytostatikum.
Warning: The word "zzgl." is invalid. The character '.' (U+2E) may not appear at the end of a word. Skipping word.
$
```

Now I removed `aspell-en` and `aspell-de` (`$sudo apt-get remove aspell-en aspell-de`) and put all the four files `qed.dat`, `qed.multi`, `qed.rws` and `qed_affix.dat` into `/usr/lib/aspell`. My `/var/lib/aspell` is empty BTW.

The new package can be selected now: gedit->Tools->Set Language...->Unknown (qed).

Regarding to the warnings in step 6 `zzlg.` words with a dot at the end are not spell-checked. I tried playing with `qed.dat` `special ' -*-` line by adding a `.` because the `de.dat` uses a `.` in there too, but it unfortunately didn't work.

**edit**

[Solved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45528/delete-last-character-in-a-word-but-only-if-the-character-is-there-in-bash) the spell-checking of words with a dot at the end by grepping these only and adding them to the spell-checking white-list.
`$ cat de_en | sed -n '/\./{s/[./]\+[^./]*$//;p}' >> /home/<username>/.config/enchant/qed.dic`

Comment: I didn't try this, but Emacs uses for example aspell, which in turn uses files (of course) as dictionaries. So, what would happen if you would merge the aspell files for German and English? Try `whereis aspell`.

Comment: Good idea by merging the two word files into one. I merged and now I need to be able to select the file in gedit->Tools->Set language. Maybe someone knows where to put it so one can select it in gedit. I googled buy couldn't find the answer so far.

Comment: Examine the directory structure where the original files were. You should replicate it, but with your new file. Probably Gedit is set to look for dictionaries at a fixed place, and the merged dictionary should behave just the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aspell Author Here.

As I said in an earlier answer, you can't just combine dictionaries from different languages and expect it to work.  You need to create a new language that combines the features of the two original languages.

Fortunately for English and German this is fairly easy; however, the suggestion quality will suffer for English words since we will disable the use of soundslike lookup.

1. Install the aspell-en and the aspell-de dictionary package
2. Go to a empty directory to keep everything clean.  Also to avoid any charset issues change the locale to "C" by setting `LC_ALL=C`.
3. Dump the English and German dictionaries into plan wordlists

   ```
   aspell dump master en > en.txt
   aspell dump master de > de.txt
   ```
4. Combine en.dat and de.dat, which you can generally find in `usr/lib/aspell`.

   The English dictionary uses soundslike lookup but that won't with the German dictionary (due to the fact that it is English specific, and more importable it is incompatible with Affix compression) so we will disable it.
   The English dictionary doesn't use affix compression but the German dictionary does so we will just use the affix file for the German dictionary.  (This will avoid having to expand the German dictionary and thus increasing it size).

   We will call the language qed, 'q' since very few languages start with q, 'e' for English, and 'g' for German.  (The language name should generally be 2 to 3 letters, but aspell doesn't really care, so en-de or some other name might work, but a 2 or 3 letter name is guaranteed to work)

   The file will be named `qed.dat` and contain the following:

   ```
   name qed
   charset iso8859-1
   special ' -*-
   soundslike      none
   affix           qed
   affix-compress  true
   ```
5. Copy `de_affix.dat` into the current directory and rename it `qed_affix.dat`.
6. Create the combined dictionary:

   ```
   cat en.txt de.txt | aspell create master -l ./qed ./qed.rws
   ```
7. Create the file `qed.multi`:

   ```
   add qed.rws
   ```
8. Test the dictionary by using `-d ./qed`.  the `./` is needed to force aspell to search the current directory.
9. Install `qed.dat` `qed.rws` `qed.multi` and `qed_affix.dat` somewhere where aspell will find it.  Please see the manual for info on how aspell searches for dictionary and language data files.
10. Done.  Everything should work now.  A more sophisticated solution will enable some form of soundslike lookup for better suggestion quality.  But that requires special care when used with affix compression (see the Aspell manual for details).  As an alternative the German dictionary can be expanded and the English soundlike lookup can be used, but that might not work so well on German words.

The case of combing English and German was easy because they both use the same charset (iso-8859-1) and because only one language used Affix compression.  Combining other languages will take more work but it is possible once you know what you are doing.  I spelled out the steps here in detail to give readers some idea of how Aspell works so a similar thing can be used for other language combinations.

If both languages use affix compression,  either the affix files will need to be combined so there are no conflicting flags, or one of the dictionaries will need to be expanded.

If the two languages use a different 8-bit charset than a compatible charset that can support both languages we need to be used.  If a standard one doesn't exist, than a new one can be created.  To avoid confusion the wordlists should be converted to utf-8 and Aspell should be instructed to expect all input and output in utf-8 instead of the charset that is used internally, which for historical reasons is the default.

Comment: I got it almost (some warnings in step 6 and "zzgl." is not spell-checked) :) Thanks to your post Kevin Atkinson :) Checkout my first post.

Comment: Yes, Aspell doesn't support special characters, such as the period ("."), at the end of a word very well.  I actually wrote about the problem (see http://aspell.net/man-html/Words-With-Symbols-in-Them.html).  There are command line flags to force Aspell to accept them when creating a dictionary (see manual) which might help, but only when the application itself is doing the parsing (splitting a line to words) and not Aspell.  With emacs I think it is Aspell that is doing the parsing.

Answer (score 5):

Vim allows to set more than one language for the spellcheck, e.g.

```
:set spelllang=de,en
```

for German and English.

Comment: I'd suggest that you change the subject as well then so as not to mislead people.

Comment: Oh you are right sorry, still a non-commandline editor is ok if I don't get gedit to work.

Comment: Have you considered gvim?

Comment: I have checked emacs and gvim but they are some kind of commandline-gui mix and not really good to use. Checkout my second edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Aspell Author Here.

You can not just combine two dictionaries from two different languages and expect it to work.  Each dictionary also has a data file associated with it that describes language specific features.

Your best bet is to create a new language which can handle both English and German correctly.  Doing so is a doable, but non-trivial task.  I might be able to help you with this task latter this week if you can't find any other solution.

General multi-language spell checking is not currently supported by Aspell (or most other spell checkers that I know of, including Hunspell).

Comment: It would be awesome if you could help creating this both-languages package :) 

I tried just pasting the content from en_affix.dat into de_affix.dat but this of course didn't work. I don't know how this all works. Having a simple file with all the words would be very easy to understand but I guess it would make the file bigger and slow down the spell-checking.