# Delete last character in a word but only if the character is there - in bash

Tags: text-processing, grep, sed

How to remove last character only if it's there?

input:

```
OpenOffice.org/m
openOffice.org/ozm
Pers.
Pfg.
phil.
Prof.
resp.
Roonstr./m
roonstr./ozm
```

desired output:

```
OpenOffice.org
openOffice.org
Pers
Pfg
phil
Prof
resp
Roonstr
roonstr
```

I got it so far that only the dot is left but unfortunately the last sed command removes also letter `g` too:
`$ cat filename | grep "\." | cut -d"/" -f1 | sed 's/.$//'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to escape the dot in your `sed` command and everything will be fine.
Like this:

```
sed 's/\.$//'
```

Because in the case you don't escape it, `.$` will match to any character at the end of string.

Also you can put all your `sed` + `grep` + `cut` into just one `sed`:

```
sed 's=/[^/]*$==;s/\.$//' filename
```

Comment: Great, thanks, works! :) I use a dictionary with over 300k lines so this is why I use grep "\." to get only the words with a dot there.

Comment: sed also can do it with smth like this:  `sed -n '/\./{s=/[^/]*$==;s/\.$//;p}`. Anyway `grep` + `sed` will work much longer than just one `sed`.

Comment: If it can be done with one sed it would be nice though. How to apply your last sed command?

Comment: `sed 's/[./]\+[^./]*$//'`

Comment: Thanks now I don't need cut, but grep is still there. A sed equivalent of my piped grep command would then remove the grep to,if it's possible, it would be nice. "Also you can put all your sed + grep + cut into just one sed" doesn't work for me, prints all the words?

Comment: @removelastdotonlyifitsthere `sed -n '/\./{s/[./]\+[^./]*$//;p}'`

Answer (score 4):

Removing a character **only if it is there** is exactly the description of parameter expansions.

```
 $ var=path.
 $ echo "$var    ${var%.}"
 path.    path
```

The dot is not special in this case (a dot is special in a regex).

The other pattern could be removed with `%/*`:

```
 $ var=openOffice.org/ozm
 $ echo "${var%/*}"
 openOffice.org
```

To remove both:

```
 $ var=roonstr./ozm
 $ var=${var%/*}
 $ var=${var%.}
 $ echo "$var"
 roonstr
```

Of course, to work with a source file it is faster to use sed on the file.
Only remember to quote the dot (to match it literally, otherwise it means: any character).

```
 $ sed 's,/.*,,;s,\.$,,' file
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Needs more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just slightly change your regular expression: to escape the `.`
And you do not need `grep`

```
cat filename | cut -d"/" -f1 | sed 's/\.$//'
```